# How to make Justify button in Word 2016 show menu for Justify Low, Medium and High (Image attached)

Tags: microsoft-word, context-menu, microsoft-word-2016

I was working on someone else's computer with Word 2016 installed and on their computer the Justify button looked like this:

[image: Justify Button with Menu]

When I was back on my computer I saw my Word 2016's Justify button did not show this menu:

[image]

**How can I enable the menu for Justify Low, Medium and High?**

Comment: This is a feature for bidirectional scripts. Are you trying to type text in, e.g., Arabic? If so, the extra options will be available if you've enabled/added the language in Word Options > Language. If not, the extra options probably don't mean what you think they mean.

Comment: Nope just English, I thought that the button would provide indented justification which looks better imo, and is done by default in Latex I think

Comment: What happens if you make the Word window *wider*? Does the option show up then?

Comment: @Twisty, No, it has nothing to do with window width. It depends on the languages that are enabled. For, e.g., Arabic, justification isn't accomplished by expanding white space but through elongation of the words in a line (_kashida_). The different justification options in Word affect how many _kashida_ characters are used. Nevertheless, after the options are enabled, they can also be applied to, e.g., English text that's entered, and they will do _something_, but not what the original poster wants, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add this option:

Click Ribbon > File > Options > Customize Ribbon.

In the "Choose commands from" choose "All commands". Then scroll down to letter "J". You need the item "Justify" with small triangle on the right side.

[image]

Select it, and click button "Add" to add it to "Home" tab in the Ribbon.

[image]